# Totalling answers from form

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form with questions that have answers such as "not true", "less true", somewhat true", "very true" and "absolutely true".

Values are "not true" = 1, "less true" = 2, "somewhat true" =3, "very true"  = 4 and "absolutely true" = 5.

How can I total up all of the answers so that when they submit the form I also get a total (I don't want them to see the total).

Answer (score 0):

Every question in a rating scale has an internal numerical value based on the number of rating options; for example, on a Good/Poor rating scale, Very Poor has a value of 1, while Very Good has a value of 5. You can reference these values in calculations to perform various functions, inlcuding generating a total:

1. Add a Calculation field to your form and set it to only appear
   internally.
2. Use an expression similar to the following to sum the total:

> =RatingScale.Question1_Rating + RatingScale.Question2_Rating + RatingScale.Question3_Rating Ratings